# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in table with different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select data from a column with  `between` operator
Looks like this:

```
select count(distinct value) 
  from dbo.OrganizationSupplementalData
 where value between 5 and 30;
```

but getting

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric
```

I also tried using CAST but it doesn't work:

```
select count(distinct value) 
  from dbo.OrganizationSupplementalData
 where cast(value as decimal(22, 8)) between 0.1 and 30.00;
```

In `value` column resides these types of data:

```
2017
2017
2017
2017
8:55:00 AM
11:00:00 AM
8:00:00 AM
8:45:00 AM
3.66
2.35
```

How can I eventually extract needed data?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you storing time, integer and decimal values in a single column (which is none of those types). The *real* problem here is your data and design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST()`:

```
where TRY_CAST(value AS DECIMAL(22, 8)) between 0.1 and 30.00
```

Obvious, the non-number values are causing a problem when you try to convert them to numbers.  `TRY_CAST()` will return `NULL` in this case.

In older, unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can use a `case` expression:

```
where (case when value not like '%[0-9.]%' and
                 value not like '%.%.%'
            then CAST(value AS DECIMAL(22, 8))
       end)
```

Comment: Wow very nice function, even version '14 supports.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, God bless you, man! Thank you very much. I couldn't understand why it doesn't convert it. Now understand the mistake and how it can be handled in the future. Thank you indeed.

Comment: @AlexanderTunick, adding that having different data types in the same column may indicate a flawed data model. Addressing the root cause may avoid the need for `TRY_CAST` or other workarounds.

Comment: @DanGuzman exactly! Cannot but agree with you! But one not, we work with client's database and it's complete landfill. Recommendations that we give to them are get taken in progress and they fix it but this process quite slow.